# Unable to activate wsp in Office 365

Tags: office-365, sandbox-solution

Today my Office 365 account is behaving strangely. Yesterday I was able to activate my wsp solution using **activate button** from the ribbon in solutions gallery.

Today I **can not activate** my wsp solution. It gives blank in popup dialog box. (As shown in below image)

[image]

When I click activate button, nothing happens.

**Note:** My user has full rights and it is site collection administrator.

Comment: Sandboxed solutions containing code has been depricated in SharePoint Online for some time now, is this such a solution? If so, MS might have started enforcing the no-code-policy fully

Comment: Yes, it's containing my event receivers in my solutions. Then how would I attach my event receivers to my list?

Comment: That's probably the problem then! In SharePoint Online you need to use the add-in model, more precisely a provider hosted add-in with remote event receivers in this scenario

Comment: Have you tried by activate it using SharePoint Online Management Shell ?or through code/console application [enter link description here](http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/2014/03/06/automated-deployment-on-sharepoint-online-using-powershell/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. As I've searched on google but can not get official announcement by Microsoft for enforcing the no-code-policy. Can you do one favor to provide me that link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has been an outage listed in the admin portal for most of the week regarding sandboxed solutions:

> SP73009 - Custom Solutions and Workflows - Service degradation Service
>   degradation - Jul 27, 2016 3:50 PM
>
> Current Status: We're continuing to perform a detailed analysis of the
>   issue to determine the next steps.
>
> User Impact: Users may be unable to activate or use SharePoint Online
>   Sandbox Solutions. This may include event receivers, workflows, web
>   parts, feature receivers, and InfoPath forms.
>
> Scope of Impact: A few customers have reported this issue, and our
>   monitoring indicates that any user attempting to activate or use this
>   feature will be affected.
>
> Start Time: Friday, July 22, 2016, at 11:30 PM UTC
>
> Next Update by: Friday, July 29, 2016, at 8:00 PM UTC

Upon further updates, it appears this is intentional and they are finally making good on their statement from 2014. http://ow.ly/zeMz302MKN1.

Comment: Oh, exiting! Could they just not stop supporting them for good this ime ;)

Comment: Thanks Eric. I was so stupid that forgot to check service maintenance in admin side. I got the exactly same issue that mentioned by you above ;-)

Comment: Happy to heard that there is some hope for sandbox solutions...

Comment: Look here http://dev.office.com/blogs/removing-code-based-sandbox-solutions-in-sharepoint-online

Comment: Yep just saw that tweet, updates answer.

Answer (score 3):

Code in sandboxed solution has been depricated by Microsoft in SharePoint Online for some time now, see [Deprication of custom code in sandboxed solutions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions/).

So that is the most possible reason for what you are experiencing.

They are now starting to enforce the no-code-policy, here is new information backing up this statement: [Removing code based sandbox solutions in SharePoint Online](http://dev.office.com/blogs/removing-code-based-sandbox-solutions-in-sharepoint-online)

What you should do is to convert your sandboxed solution to an [add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930.aspx), most likely a [provider-hosted add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

As per the Microsoft, as shown in the **Admin > Service Health** currently SharePoint Online service is `degraded`. Next Update from Microsoft will be on `Monday, August 1, 2016, at 8:00 PM UTC`.

Check the service health.

[image]

Comment: Now Microsoft stop supporting Managed Code in Sandbox Solution, Office365 as per their announcement in 2014. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions/

Comment: Take a look here http://dev.office.com/blogs/removing-code-based-sandbox-solutions-in-sharepoint-online